# How to pass default params to each routes in react navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have this router config:

```
export const Bird = StackNavigator({
    ResidentBirds: {
        screen: BirdList,
        navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
            title: 'Resident Birds',
        })
    },
    MigratoryBirds: {
        screen: BirdList,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'Migratory Birds'
        }
    }
});
```

Both the routes have the same screen component (**BirdList**).

BirdList.js:

```
export default class BirdList extends React.Component {
    state = {
        fetching: false,
        dataSource: []
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getBirds();
    }

    getBirds = () => {
        // const birdType = this.props.navigation.state.params.birdType;
        // const args = this.pros.navigation.state.params.args;

        // fetch list of birds of type birdType
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}}>
                <Text>Fetching birds: {this.state.fetching.toString()}</Text>
                <FlatList
                    data={this.state.dataSource}
                    ...
                />
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

App.js:

```
import {Bird} from './src/config/router'
export default class App extends React.Component {
    ...

    render() {
        return <Bird/>
    }
}
```

My question is how can I pass default params to the Routes (i.e., ResidentBirds and MigratoryBirds) so that I can use that values to fetch appropriate data?

Maybe something like this:

```
export const Bird = StackNavigator({
    ResidentBirds: {
        screen: BirdList,
        navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
            title: 'Resident Birds',
        }),
        params: {
            birdType: 'Resident',
            args: {
                'height': 100,
                'region': 'America'
            }
        }
    },
    MigratoryBirds: { 
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you put any condition while navigating to these screens ? How are you navigating to these screens ?

Comment: @ParasWatts I am importing Bird from the router to the App component. I have updated and added App.js code. Please have a look.

Comment: you can pass parameter while navigating to screens

Comment: navigate('ScreenName', { ParamName: 'ParamValue' })}

Comment: Access it like this 
    const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;

params.ParamName to access value of parameters

Comment: @ParasWatts I know how to pass params when navigating from one screen to another. I think you didn't understand my question. What I want is to have an initial default value for each of the routes. Since both the routes have the same component, I want to pass a different initial value to each of the routes which then will be passed to the component and then even though it is the same component, it will be able to load different data according to the routes default initial param values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Working solution by Spencer [in github](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/2392):

```
export const Bird = StackNavigator({
    ResidentBirds: {
        screen: (props) => <BirdList {...props} birdType="Resident" args={{ height: 100, region: 'America' }} />,
        navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
            title: 'Resident Birds',
        })
    },
    ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this! One note: if you have `navigationOptions` inside the screen component itself, then this approach breaks that --> if you specify `screen` as a function like this then you must move `navigationOptions` in here also.